# Merge always do rebase

Tags: git

I'm telling my developers don't use git merge command instead of that use git rebase.
My requirement is if a user/developer accidentally  hits git merge command i want disable the git merge (command) from git always.

Is that Possible to achieve This?

Or
if the developer hits git merge it will perform rebase.

Comment: Do you have an SVN background? Or why do you insist on always rebase? With `git`, merge is the much less problematic approach: A rebase creates new commits that have never been tested, while a merge records history the way it happened, giving much more utility to tools like `git bisect`. You really don't want to avoid merges with `git`.

Comment: You can check in a server-side hook like `pre-receive` if the new commits include any merge commit. If any, fail the push and tell the user to use `git pull -r` to flatten the branch.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of a [pre-receive hook which detect any merge commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33248257/6309), you can also request for your team to use, [with Git 2.6+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309):

```sh
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global  rebase.autoStash true
```

Any `git pull` would actually be a `git pull --rebase`, forcing them to always replay their local (yet to be pushed) commits on top of an updated remote tracking branch.

Comment: If a developer fire git merge branch_name i dont want to execute that command and given an error message like git rebase only is that really possible ?

Comment: @G.kalyan Yes, either though pre-receive hook on the server side, or through a prepare-commit-msg hook on the client side (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19460322/6309)

Comment: can u please share the script or code of pre-receive hook it really helpful for me Thanks

Comment: @G.kalyan That code would follow what is presented in the first link of the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33248257/6309

Answer (score 0):

This option (git config --global pull.rebase true) will only work when I am trying to pull the changes from remote. But this doesn't work when I merging one local branch onto another. What is best way to disable merge command in git locally and globally both ?

Comment: This is not an answer but rather a question. Maybe it makes sense to ask this as a separate question or as a comment to the answer above